# XML validation against XSD failed, with exception: cvc-pattern-valid -Wired validation error

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I am making a request to a soap web service and as a response I am getting the following result:

```
XML validation against XSD failed, with exception: cvc-pattern-valid: Value '‎L91806031N' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{8}[a-zA-Z]{1}' for type
```

As you can see the input matches the pattern, are there any thoughts why this thing is happening?

Comment: No idea. Please tell us which XSD processor you are using, and give a complete repro, so people can try to reproduce the problem.